# NSTextView's textViewDidChangeSelection not called when option-command-dragging

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

I have an NSTextView.

textViewDidChangeSelection is being called when I drag to change the selection or if I command-drag, or if I option-drag, but not when I option-command-drag.

Sometimes the log will output the following:

```
[Framework] Shared items array is empty
[Framework] No shared items can be accessed
```

Option-command-dragging of course does change the selection, so I'd like to be notified when an option-command drag happens.

Comment: Regarding the log output, I have discussed similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64662418/mousemoved-notification-in-nstextview-produces-message-shared-items-array-is-em 
It doesn't seem to be dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRanges" documentation says that it is only called when the "stillSelecting" argument of setSelectedRange or setSelectedRanges is set to false.  So I subclassed NSTextView to override that argument like this:

```
class NeverStillSelectingTextView : NSTextView {

override func setSelectedRanges(_ ranges: [NSValue], affinity: NSSelectionAffinity, stillSelecting stillSelectingFlag: Bool) {
    super.setSelectedRanges(ranges, affinity: affinity, stillSelecting: false)
}

override func setSelectedRange(_ charRange: NSRange, affinity: NSSelectionAffinity, stillSelecting stillSelectingFlag: Bool) {
    super.setSelectedRange(charRange, affinity: affinity, stillSelecting: false)
}
}
```

And now willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRanges is always called when you command-option drag.